# How do I catch SSLengine problem and send an error response, instead of a broken pipe error ?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

I have my server cert in the trust-store, if a signed client cert comes everything is processed normally. But if I get a cert which can not be verified with the cert already present in the truststore, is it possible to send an error message instead of a broken pipe error ? 
I want to handle the sslhandshakeexception and give an error response. 
I am using spring security with x509 configuration and the truststore as a jks.

I do not want to disable ssl verification, I want the unsigned certs which can not be verified with the truststore to return an access denied message instead of returning nothing and showing a broken pipe, sslhandshakeexception in the logs.

I am defining the truststore in the application.yml 
as ssl.server.trust-store: truststore.jks and ssl.server.trust-store-password: changeit .

For the configurations I am following this

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2018/08/x-509-client-certificates-with-spring-security/